# Trying to build project with appfuse

Tags: appfuse

I building my project with app fuse but unable to create it. Can any one help me to build appfuse spring project.

Answer (score 0):

[Appfuse samle project creation](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart)
in this link you can create a sample appfuse project .

1. Create a appfuse project using the link.
2. Import the project to your eclipse.
3. Right Click the pom.xml file goto Run-As and click Maven install wait until the process completed.
4. Now run your project in apache tomcat server.

   If you need basic spring application you can refer this link [Sample Spring example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-annotation-example/)

   If you need appfuse spring sample Try this [Appfuse github](https://github.com/appfuse/appfuse)